# QML-Move item with arrow keys

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using Qt version 5.6.0 from windows 8.1. I draw a shape that has 4 sides and the ability to drag its apexes.I want to move apexes of shape with arrow keys.I use this code but it does not work.
Point.qml:

```
Item {
id: root

signal dragged()
property alias color :point.color
Rectangle {
    id:point
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 20
    height: 20

    opacity: 0.2

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: root
        onPositionChanged: {
            if(drag.active) {
                dragged()
            }
        }
        onClicked: point.focus=true;
    }

    //        Keys.onPressed: {
    //            console.log("move");
    //            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Left) {
    //                console.log("move left");
    //                event.accepted = true;
    //                point.x-=1;
    //            }
    //        }
    //        Keys.onRightPressed: {
    //            console.log("move");
    //            point.x+=1;
    //        }

    //        Keys.onLeftPressed: {
    //            console.log("move");
    //            point.x-=1;
    //        }
    Keys.onPressed: {
        switch(event.key) {
        case Qt.Key_Left: point.x-=1;
            break;
        case Qt.Key_Right: point.x+=1;
            break;
        case Qt.Key_Up: point.y-=1;
            break;
        case Qt.Key_Down: point.y+=1;
            break;
        }
    }

    focus: true;
}}
```

main.qml:

```
 Point {
    id: pointA
    x: 50
    y: 50
}

Point {
    id: pointB
    x: 250
    y: 50
}

Point {
    id: pointC
    x: 250
    y: 250
}

Point {
    id: pointD
    x: 50
    y: 250
}


Item {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPaint: {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.moveTo(pointA.x, pointA.y);
            ctx.lineTo(pointB.x, pointB.y);
            ctx.lineTo(pointC.x, pointC.y);
            ctx.lineTo(pointD.x, pointD.y);
            ctx.lineTo(pointA.x, pointA.y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            pointA.dragged.connect(repaint)
            pointB.dragged.connect(repaint)
            pointC.dragged.connect(repaint)
            pointD.dragged.connect(repaint)
        }

        function repaint() {
            var ctx = getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            requestPaint()
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
main.qml:

```
PhotoPreview {
                            id : photoPreview
                            anchors.fill : parent
                            //focus:true //visible
                            visible: capture
                        }
```

photopreview.qml:

```
Item {
  id:mywin    
  property real defaultSize:mywin.width
property var currentFrame: undefined
property real surfaceViewportRatio: 1.5
focus: true    
ScrollView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    flickableItem.interactive: true
    frameVisible: true
    highlightOnFocus: true           
    Flickable {
        id: flick
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: parent.width
        contentHeight: parent.height
        property alias source :image.source
        signal closed
        Rectangle {
            id: photoFrame
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            color:"transparent"
            scale:defaultSize / parent.width
            Behavior on scale { NumberAnimation { duration: 200 } }
            Behavior on x { NumberAnimation { duration: 200 } }
            Behavior on y { NumberAnimation { duration: 200 } }                
            smooth: true
            antialiasing: true                
            Image {
                id:image
                anchors.fill: parent
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                smooth: true
            }
            PinchArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                pinch.target: photoFrame
                pinch.minimumRotation: -360
                pinch.maximumRotation: 360
                pinch.minimumScale: 0.1
                pinch.maximumScale: 10
                pinch.dragAxis: Pinch.XAndYAxis
                property real zRestore: 0
                onSmartZoom: {
                    if (pinch.scale > 0) {
                        photoFrame.rotation = 0;
                        photoFrame.scale = Math.min(mywin.width, mywin.height) / Math.max(image.sourceSize.width, image.sourceSize.height) * 0.85
                        photoFrame.x = flick.contentX + (flick.width - photoFrame.width) / 2
                        photoFrame.y = flick.contentY + (flick.height - photoFrame.height) / 2
                        zRestore = photoFrame.z
                        photoFrame.z = ++mywin.highestZ;
                    } else {
                        photoFrame.rotation = pinch.previousAngle
                        photoFrame.scale = pinch.previousScale
                        photoFrame.x = pinch.previousCenter.x - photoFrame.width / 2
                        photoFrame.y = pinch.previousCenter.y - photoFrame.height / 2
                        photoFrame.z = zRestore
                        --mywin.highestZ
                    }
                }                    
                MouseArea {
                    id: dragArea
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag.target: photoFrame
                    scrollGestureEnabled: false  // 2-finger-flick gesture should pass through to the Flickable
                    onPressed: {
                        photoFrame.z = ++mywin.highestZ;
                    }                        
                    onWheel: {
                        if (wheel.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier) {
                            photoFrame.rotation += wheel.angleDelta.y / 120 * 5;
                            if (Math.abs(photoFrame.rotation) < 4)
                                photoFrame.rotation = 0;
                        } else {
                            photoFrame.rotation += wheel.angleDelta.x / 120;
                            if (Math.abs(photoFrame.rotation) < 0.6)
                                photoFrame.rotation = 0;
                            var scaleBefore = photoFrame.scale;
                            photoFrame.scale += photoFrame.scale * wheel.angleDelta.y / 120 / 10;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                
            Point {
                id: pointA
                x: image.width/4
                y: image.height/4
                color: "blue"
            }
            Point {
                id: pointB
                x: image.width/2
                y: image.height/2
                color: "blue"                    
            }                
            Point {
                id: pointD
                x: image.width/4
                y: image.height/2
                color: "red"
            }                
            Point {
                id: pointC
                x: image.width/2
                y: image.height/4
                color: "red"                    
            }                
            Item {
                anchors.fill: parent                    
                Canvas {
                    id: canvas
                    anchors.fill: parent                        
                    onPaint: {
                        //...
                    }
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        //...
                    }                        
                    function repaint() {
                        //..
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `ScrollView` that inherit `FocusScope`, which needs to have `focus:true` to [forward it](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-input-focus.html#acquiring-focus-and-focus-scopes). 
You instead are setting `focus` to `PhotoPreview`, which is plain `Item` that are not supposed to be focused.

So you need to simple remove `focus:visible` and set it to `ScrollView`.

The better fix is to remove that redundant `Item`, and leave `ScrollView` as `PhotoPreview` root item, with all its properties and signals.

Comment: @neda you may change your question and swap irreveland code with one that use ScrollView to make this question more usefull for others and maybe gains some reputation points.

Answer (score 2):

In `Point.qml` the key event handler tries to change the x, y of `point`, however `point` is a rectangle that `anchors.centerIn: parent`. The key event handler should change `root` x, y instead:

```
//in Point.qml
case Qt.Key_Left: 
    root.x-=1;
    break;
```

`Point` now changes it's position when keyboard event is triggered. Next, `Point` needs to notify the `Canvas` in `main.qml` to repaint. `Point` can emit `dragged` signal after changing it's x, y:

```
//in Point.qml
Keys.onPressed: {
    switch(event.key) {
    case Qt.Key_Left: 
        root.x-=1;
        dragged();
        break;
    case Qt.Key_Right: 
        root.x+=1;
        dragged();
        break;
    case Qt.Key_Up: 
        root.y-=1;
        dragged();
        break;
    case Qt.Key_Down: 
        root.y+=1;
        dragged();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. I put my project in this [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=99118753564009318516)